# CSS formating in HTML select options using fontawwesome

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have a bog standard select list in HTML that I am trying to use as a listbox.

Current code looks like:

```
    <select size="20" style="font-family: Arial, FontAwesome; width: 200px;">
        <option value="1">&#xf00d; icon-master</option>
        <option value="2">&#xf2b9; address-book</option>
        <option value="3">&#xf042; adjust</option>
        <option value="4"> air-freshener</option>
        <option value="5">&#xf015; icon-home</option>
        <option value="6">&#xf018; icon-road</option>
    </select>
```

This does work, but I have one or two issues.

This is what it looks like on screen:

[image: View of HTML above]

I say one or two as it may be the same thing. Looking at the image against icon-master, and address-book, they are of different widths. Is it possible to format this so that all of the text lines up?

Finally, there is no image for air-freshener, can this also be formatted in the same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the icons as pseudo elements, loading them using their unicode like "*f2b9*" and give them a width. This way they will have a space, even without the icon.

```css
option:before {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  text-align: center;
}

option.cross:before {
  content: "\f00d";
}

option.default:before {
  content: "\f2b9";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/53b22dcfd4.js"></script>

<select size="20" style="width: 200px;">
    <option value="1" class="cross">icon-master</option>
    <option value="2" class="default">address-book</option>
    <option value="3" class="default">adjust</option>
    <option value="4">air-freshener</option>
</select>
```

[**JSFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfuwjz6g/1/)